# macOS Visual Studio Code NO suggestions for robot framework file only

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework, autosuggest

I have enabled all of the suggestions fields and checked together with senior, also googled, but we haven't found a reason for that.
I am using
robotframework (helloworld.robot)
SeleniumLibrary
Python

I have tried in settings, but no success

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [Robot Framework Language Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robocorp.robotframework-lsp) extension in extension store.

[image]